# How to access the isolated scope of a modal window instance?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

In order to dynamically add and remove a window class to my modal window I have overwritten the modal window template and added a further ng-class check for modelShake:

```
$templateCache.put('template/modal/window.html',
    "<div tabindex=\"-1\" role=\"dialog\" class=\"modal fade\" ng-class=\"{in: animate}\" ng-style=\"{'z-index': 1050 + index*10, display: 'block'}\" ng-click=\"close($event)\">\n" +
    "    <div class=\"modal-dialog animated\" ng-class=\"{'modal-sm': size == 'sm', 'modal-lg': size == 'lg', 'shake': modalShake}\"><div class=\"modal-content\" ng-transclude></div></div>\n" +
    "</div>");
```

I am having problems however to modify the value of modalShake once the modal dialog is displayed as I did not find a way to access the isolated scope of the modal window from the controller given to the $modal provider.

Any ideas and help would be appreciated.

Comment: you could navigate through the scope tree, but that would defeat the point of having an isolate scope in the directive. I strongly advise you to modify the directive rather than put this in the controller. Make it so you can pass `modalShake` to the directive through an attribute.

Comment: Try $parent.modalShake

Comment: Not yet unfortunately. The $parent does not work, I will probably do it through some attribute. The only downside is that I have to modify/overwrite the angular-ui code to make this work.